# Как сделать подсказку в PasswordBox в wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

Делаю окно регистрации. Есть поле для ввода пароля, состоящее из TextBox(отображается введенный пароль), PasswordBox(пароль скрыт), CheckBox(переключает показ пароля). Как сделать подсказку для поля, чтобы если в passwordbox или textbox было "", она показывалась поверх?
Разметка xaml:

```
    <TextBox Name="pwdTextBox" 
             Grid.Column="1"
             Grid.Row="2"
             Visibility="Visible"
             Margin="30 12"
             Style="{StaticResource LoginTextBox}"
             Text=""/>
    <PasswordBox Name="pwdPasswordBox" 
                 Grid.Column="1" 
                 Grid.Row="2"
                 Margin="30 12"
                 BorderThickness="0"
                 Background="Transparent"
                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                 Password=""/>
    <CheckBox Name="checkBoxPwd" 
              Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.Row="2"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Margin="0 0 35 0"
              Click="CheckBox_Click"/>
    
    <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False" FontSize="14" 
               Text="Введите пароль!" Grid.Row="2" Margin="44 0" 
               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
               Foreground="#FF95ABD3"
               Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                   //здесь какое-то условие для отображения
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
```

Логика кнопки:

```
    private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var checkBox = sender as CheckBox;
        if (checkBox.IsChecked.Value)
        {
            pwdTextBox.Text = pwdPasswordBox.Password;
            pwdTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            pwdPasswordBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        else
        {
            pwdPasswordBox.Password = pwdTextBox.Text;
            pwdTextBox.Text = "";
            pwdPasswordBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```